# vague behaviour by pointer in snippet

Tags: c++, pointers

I was working with pointers and was trying different things.

So here I made a general print function

```
void print(const int &value)
{
     cout << "value = " << value << " & address = " << &value << endl;
}
```

Now Here's a code that works somehow:

```
  int j = 9090;
  int* p;
  *p = j; //Please read further
  print(*p);
```

I know *p = j is something illogical and I should have done p = &j or p = new int etc.... but why did this work?
The output was

```
value = 9090 & address = 0x28ff48
```

Moreover if I print j, the address is 0x28ff44. Which means it allocated new memory automatically for p (as its address is ..48)

Now, if I only add another line before j's declaration:

```
int i = 80;
int j = 9090;
int* p;
*p = j; //Please read further
print(*p);
```

^The program crashes.

However if I add this i's line after declaration of p the program runs.

```
int j = 9090;
int* p;
int i = 80;
*p = j;
print(*p);
```

Am I doing something wrong? I was using GCC compiler in Dev C++ IDE 4.9.9.2. What's going on?

Comment: "*Which means it allocated new memory automatically for p *" -- no. The value of `p` is garbage, which accidentally happened to point to a valid region of memory.

Comment: aah, yes. If i declare p first as "int *p = 0; " then the program crashes regardless of any modifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int* p;
*p = j;
```

This is correct syntax of C++. It means that in field which address is in p, you put value of j. The problem with crash originate from the fact that you don't provide any memory for p. When you say int * p it means that you have pointer on int variable. However you didn't provide any real address in memory to store int value. There is some rubbish in p but this rubbish is considered to be valid address by program and it tries to write value of j there. If you are lucky and this address was not used the program will work further. Otherwise it will crash. To avoid such undefined behaviour you need to allocate memory for p:

```
int* p = new int;
*p = j;
```

Comment: I know what you're saying. But that was what I was asking that why was it working without allocation any new memory for it.

Comment: I've edited my post and explaned reason why your program crashes in some cases and don't crash in others. To explain it not in general but exactly with your case (why switching i declaration leads to crash/no crash) you need to provide machine code generated by your compiler and memory trace of your machine on program start.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that dereferencing an uninitialised pointer is *undefined*.

This means that anything can happen - sometimes a program will crash, sometimes just give strange results, and sometimes (if you're unlucky) it will just seem to work.

Since your pointer is uninitialised, you will access memory at whatever random location it happens to represent.
Sometimes, this is a valid address, and the program will keep running.
Sometimes, it's an invalid address, and the program will crash.

Answer (score 1):

> I know *p = j is something illogical

In this case it is undefined behavior. You are dereferencing a pointer that wasn't initialized, so it effectively points to an unknown (random) location.

> Which means it allocated new memory automatically for p

No, it didn't. The address you see is just the random, undefined value which ended up in your uninitialized pointer.

> why did this work?

That's the thing with undefined behavior: It might work by coincidence, for example if the random value in the pointer happened to point into some valid, writable memory region, your code would work fine for that specific run. Another time, it might just crash. Yet another time, it might corrupt your heap, or some unrelated data, and cause a seemingly unrelated crash or bug some time later. Which is just screaming for long nights in front of your debugger ;)

Bottom line: **Don't do it** - avoid UB at all cost.

> However if I add this i's line after declaration of p the program runs.

I think the behavior you observe (crash vs. no crash) is not directly related to the code changes, but coincidental. In fact, if you'd run the "working" version multiple times, I'm sure you'd still get a crash after some time.